# Is there a character that looks like "ot," or is it a different language?

Tags: kana, video-games

I'm playing a game and don't recognise this character. It looks like an "ot" or "of" to me, but that might just be the font. I can only read the following: どんな夢も[ ]うんだって

[image: in-game text]

Can someone help me understand what it is and why it is used? It's an old game, so this is the highest quality I could get the image.

Comment: Do you know any Japanese and kanji at all? Or did you OCR that line to get 「どんな夢も[ ]うんだって」?

Comment: I know some Japanese but still learning. I moved when I was young and my parents didn't teach me, so I only started learning in late teen years and early adulthood. I'm still not familiar with most kanji, so I tried to write it myself and looked at a database to find the closest thing. I apologise if the one I said is incorrect. It looked a bit wrong to me but I was struggling to find anything that fit more. Also, I can read hiragana. I didn't use OCR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 叶う{かなう}

The kanji is [叶](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8F%B6)

> どんな夢も叶うんだって